# Windows service starts and then stops, can't figure out the bug

Tags: c#, .net, xml, windows-services, webrequest

I am trying to read a file at constant intervals and then send the data queried to a specific webserver. The following is the code I am using, but the service starts and stops without doing any thing. I can't Figure out the bug.

```
public partial class IPTProjectService : ServiceBase
{
    private Thread checkingThread;
    private System.Timers.Timer timer;
    Boolean sendingTime;

    public IPTProjectService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        checkingThread = new Thread(update);
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(Properties.Settings.Default.TIMEINTERVAL);
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        sendingTime = true;
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        setSendingTime();
        if (!File.Exists("Testfile.txt"))
        {
            File.Create("Testfile.txt");
            timer_Elapsed(sender, e);
        }
        else
        {
            File.WriteAllText("Testfile.txt", timer.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void setSendingTime()
    {
        sendingTime = true;
    }

    private void update()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (sendingTime)
            {
                CarpoolWebClient.sendData(Properties.Settings.Default.DATAFILE);
                sendingTime = false;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            timer.Start();
            checkingThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Fail(ex.ToString());
        }

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
            timer.Stop();
            checkingThread.Abort();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("testfile.txt", true);
            writer.Write(e.ToString());
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}

class CarpoolWebClient
{
    public static void sendData(String fileName)
    {
        WebRequest req = null;
        WebResponse rsp = null;

        try
        {
            //URL of message broker
            string uri = "http://localhost/IPTProject/receive_xml.php";
            req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "text/xml";

            // Wrap the request stream with a text-based writer
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
            // Write the xml text into the stream
            writer.WriteLine(GetTextFromXMLFile(@fileName));
            writer.Close();
            rsp = req.GetResponse();

        }
        catch (WebException webEx)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(webEx.Message);
            throw webEx;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (req != null) req.GetRequestStream().Close();
            if (rsp != null) rsp.GetResponseStream().Close();
        }
    }

    private static string GetTextFromXMLFile(string file)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
        string ret = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the event log? Unhandled service exceptions are usually logged to there.

Comment: Not sure if it matters but you should always call the base method when you override it (base.OnStart() and base.OnStop())

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by not having a service running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was requesting the webserver on my own computer i.e. localhost, I didn't noticed that wampserver was not running. I checked the event log which showed me the WebException. Starting the wampserver code works fine. Thank you every one.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, debug the service. If it's a problem because the service is set to automatically start then you can use this "trick" to [automatically attach the debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed.aspx) and figure out what is going wrong that way.

Answer (score 0):

The call to

```
File.Create("Testfile.txt");
timer_Elapsed(sender, e);
```

will create a file and return a `FileStream` to the newly created file.  This file is subsequently still open then `timer_Elapsed` is called and will cause the application to fail as it cannot open the file a second time. See the [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx) on the subject.

The Create call is not required for your code, you can simplyfying the method to the example below, and it should resolve this issue. Alternatively, close the `FileStream` object.

```
void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    setSendingTime();
    File.WriteAllText("Testfile.txt", timer.ToString());
}
```

`File.WriteAllText` will create the file is it does not exist, and overwrite the file if it does exist, effectively doing the same thing as your check.

If this does not resolve the issue, check the event log for errors, or alternatively provided error handling code in your `timer_Elapsed` and `update` methods that log the error message.

Comment: There is a `!File.Exists` *before* `File.Create` is called so I doubt this is what the problem is.

Comment: @James This is an educated guess by viewing the code.  Without a definite error message one cannot be sure.  However,  If the file does not exist, and the odds are it does not exist on first run as it has yet to be created, then what would happen... :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I encountered similar issues a lot of times...

1. Log all uncaught exceptions:

   ```
       // Somewhere at the start of the constructor:
       AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

   [...]

   void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
   {
       // Log exeption e.ExceptionObject.ToString to a file
   }
   ```
2. Also, I would use a try-catch + log in the update method to make sure that if the thread exits for any unknown reason, you find out the reason.
3. If these things don't work, it's usually something stupid like a missing DLL, the incorrect version of a DLL (64/32-bit mix), or something like that. This can be found in the event log.

That should do it :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this on a machine that has Visual Studio installed (e.g., your dev machine), add a call to

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

in your startup or wherever appropriate. This will launch the Visual Studio debugger, so you don't have to fight with timing issues (Service stopping before you can manually attach the debugger)